# How should i determine for virtual dedicated hosting?

Tags: windows

What are all the criteria i should determine if i want to choose a virtual dedicated server?
I have asp.net website that has 3800 vistors per day that is hosted on a shared hosting.
Kindly advise me if i should upgrade it to VPS?? 
What is the advantage and disadvantage of using VPS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The big differences:

1. With a VPS you'll get (more or less) dedicated resources, so performance will be more consistent.  With shared hosting you'll often get cut off temporarily if you use too many resources.  With a VPS your site will usually just slow down rather than being shut down entirely.
2. You'll likely get MORE resources with a VPS vs. a shared hosting account.
3. You'll typically get root/admin access to the virtual server, so you can install software.

Things to look for:

1. Memory is a big one.  VPS's tend to skimp on memory, so if you have to run a web server and database on your VPS things could get tight.
2. Backups are also big.  Make sure your provider backs up your virtual server or you do it yourself.  With shared hosting the whole server is typically backed up by the provider, but that isn't always the case with VPS's.
3. Administration - with shared hosting the provider will typically take care of software updates/patches/etc.  With a VPS that is generally up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first questions would be:
Are you currently having performance problems?
Are your users complaining of slow page load times?
Is your shared host overloaded?

VPS are still on a shared machine but you have much more if not full control over the environment.  Performance depends on the VPS package you purchase.  They are normally sold by how much RAM, disk space, and bandwidth you require.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys. one more query, so if i buy a VPS from GOdaddy(bcoz it's cheap :) ) the SQL server also will be part of the same VPS rite? If its on the same server, what will be the capacity of the server in terms of number users can access the site per month? considering the server has 512mb of ram and 90% of the site operation is just readonly(users will not post anything)?